# BIRT - expression builder: HTML Table + Dataset field does not evaluate

Tags: birt, expressionbuilder

I am new to BIRT and its awesome but I am unable to make a bullet point list where each bullet point is a field from my dataset. Without using any html the datasetfield evaluates but as soon as I add an html tag it will simply show the name of the field.

This

```
<ul>
  <li><value-of> row["SRRI"] </value-of></li>
</ul>
```

Shows:

- row["SRRI"]

But I want it to show the value of row["SRRI"] instead. (Omitting "" does not change the output for me)

I was searching for a solution for a few hours now and I guess its fairly simple but I cannot find a solution on how to tell BIRT that this is not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a list, and you want to lead each entry with a bullet point. In your report design, you can put a cell in front of your row["SRRI"] value and put what ever bullet image you want there.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but maybe it could be helpful for any others. It simply sounds like your text item is set to auto instead of html.
[image]